# How to avoid using loops to build numpy arrays. Code cleaning advice

Tags: python, loops, numpy

I am writing some code to generate some simulated data but the only way I know how to build this up is to use loops and ideally I would like to avoid this.

So far my code looks like this. 
Basically I need to apply some different scaling to each of the rows in my 2d array which I am currently doing with a loop.

```
n_echelle = 70
n_obs_echelle = 20

px_echelle1 = np.random.uniform(0, 2048, size(n_echelle,n_obs_echelle))





theta_values = []

for i in range(0,n_echelle):
    theta = np.array([-0.03**(0.5+(i/300)),10000-180*i**(0.92)])
    theta_values.append(theta)

theta_values = np.asarray(theta_values)






wl_echelle1 = []

for i in range(0,n_echelle):
    d = np.polyval(theta_values[i], px_echelle1[i])
    wl_echelle1.append(d)

wl_echelle1 = np.asarray(wl_echelle1)
```

Later on I have to do the inverse of this, It seems absurd that I am doing all of this in loops

```
theta_values_reverse = []

for i in range(0,n_echelle):
    theta_reverse = np.array([-0.03**-(0.5+(i/300)),(0.03**-(0.5+i/300))*(10000-180*i**(0.92))])
    theta_values_reverse.append(theta_reverse)

theta_values_reverse = np.asarray(theta_values_reverse)


px_echelle2 = []

for i in range(0,n_echelle):
    d = np.polyval(theta_values_reverse[i], wl_echelle1[i])
    px_echelle2.append(d)


px_echelle2 = np.asarray(px_echelle2)
```

Any feed back/suggestions are welcome. Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure soliciting advice fits in a question and answer site. This isn't a discussion forum

Comment: There is literally an option to ask for advice when asking a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps a little.

```
n_echelle = 70
n_obs_echelle = 20
px_echelle1 = np.random.uniform(0, 2048, size(n_echelle,n_obs_echelle))

wl_echelle1 = np.zeros(n_echelle)
i=np.arange(n_echelle)
theta_values = np.array([-0.03**(0.5+(i/300)),10000-180*i**(0.92)])

for ii in range(0,n_echelle):
    wl_echelle1[ii] = np.polyval(theta_values[:,ii], wl_echelle1[ii])
```

This should create a 2x70 array for your theta values.
Im not familiar with the polyval command, and im not sure there are other solitions than looping. Let me know if you find something